# ASP.NET Web API + async + EF6.2: Long delay before closing DB connection

Tags: asp.net, async-await, entity-framework-6

I have implemented an ASP.NET Web API controller with many different API methods that all make some DB calls using EF6.2. For scalability reasons I preferred to make all EF calls async.

I have read about issues, when combining ASP.NET with async -- something related to AspNetSynchronizationContext? But as far as I understand, it should be allright, as long as the Web API methods are implemented as async themselves, and async is used all the way down to the EF async calls.

A bit simplified, the pattern I have used goes like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MethodXX(int id)
    {
        MyDTO dataToReturn;
        using (IMyStore store = DbStore) {
           dataToReturn = await store.SomeMethodAsync(id)
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, dataToReturn, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter)
    }
```

where DbStore creates and returns an object that inherits from:

```
public class StoreWithDbContext: IDisposable
{
    protected StoreWithDbContext()
    {
        DbContext = DbContextFactory.GetContext();
    }

    protected XXXContext DbContext { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

where XXXContext inherits from DbContext (EF), and store.SomeMethodAsync() eventually will end up awaiting a call to some async method in the EF.

Now, in more or less all cases, this code seems to work just fine. But I have a specific case, where I'm running into some strange trouble. I suspect, maybe because the DB call is taking a bit longer in this case (more than 2 seconds). I have enabled logging on the EF DbContext, and what I see in this specific case is this:

```
Opened connection asynchronously at 08-09-2021 11:58:15 +02:00
SELECT 
    [UnionAll2].[ID] AS [C1], 
    [UnionAll2].[ID1] AS [C2], 
    [UnionAll2].[ID2] AS [C3], 
    ...<removed>

-- Executing asynchronously at 08-09-2021 11:58:15 +02:00

-- Completed in 2626 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

Then nothing happens for a VERY long time. It seems like the thread is hanging or is blocked, when it wants to resume from the await. At first, I thought it was a permanent deadlock. But eventually, after **~5minutes**, this message appears:

```
Closed connection at 08-09-2021 12:03:23 +02:00
```

And then the API method resumes and completes successfully.

Does anyone have an idea, why there is a pause of 5 minutes, before the connection is closed?

NOTE: This issue appears consistently, when the API method is called with a specific parameter. For other parameters, the issue is not present. My suspicion is, that it is because this specific parameter causes the SQL query to take longer time (more than 2 seconds).

Comment: Are you using an explicit database transaction, or an implicit one using TransactionScope? When a transaction is open DbContext can't close the connection before the transaction itself either commits or rolls back. That's typically an application bug as DbContext is already a Unit-of-Work and persists all changes to the database using an internal transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. When left to work as intended, a DbContext will only open a connection when needed, ie when loading data or saving changes. It will close the connection immediately after use

Comment: The issue arises in a read-only case, i.e. just SELECT .... And there is no explicit creation of a transaction.